# Why WKWebView is not loading pdf in iOS using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using WKWebView to preview files from web url but some url are opened some are not. I don't know the reason why it is happening the urls are seeming identical but the url which is not getting loaded in WKWebView is getting downloaded in safari rather than opening.

working url:
https://test.store.digiboxx.com:9000/9d2830d7cdec4de2/mayavati/413780_2CB2E888-CCE2-474D-8549-00270F92C6F0_New_pfd.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=asdklhfgdefyu%2F20201220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201220T131747Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=204841a52ddfc4d003f4b0bea45488b45a347fcd8e694011c9de4680afcebe9c

Problematic url: https://test.store.digiboxx.com:9000/9d2830d7cdec4de2/mayavati/F6685A44-E65F-4A6F-9E8A-34DA333C3E2F_New_pfd.pdf?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=asdklhfgdefyu%2F20201220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20201220T131840Z&X-Amz-Expires=604800&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=85efaa80b4e53a47869c82b4dbe64c9bfa6417991184abf69891d71a19a986a9

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: otherDocumentView.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.otherDocumentView.addSubview(webView)
        let myRequest = NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: fileURL)! as URL)
        webView.load(myRequest as URLRequest)
```

Comment: The same difference happens when you click on the URLs in a Chrome browser, so it has likely more to do with the way the web server responds to them, than with WKWebView.

Comment: Why are you not using `PDFView`?

Answer (score 0):

```
if let pdf = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("myPDF", withExtension: 
"pdf", subdirectory: nil, localization: nil)  {
            let req = NSURLRequest(URL: pdf)
            let webView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(20,20,self.view.frame.size.width-40,self.view.frame.size.height-40))
            webView.loadRequest(req)
            self.view.addSubview(webView)
        }
```